# programmatically create a dynamic worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

(see image below)

I have a set of excel workbooks in a folder. I want to copy data from those files to another excel master sheet. The master sheet will be filled depending on the number of files on the folder.

[image]

[image]

On the source file, J20 + J18 should be on the yellow box. There is some editing needs to be done first.

This is what I have so far:

```
    Set dstWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\master.xlsx")
    Set dstWS = dstWB.Sheets("CPU")

    Set srcWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\CPU\Source1_CPU.xlsx", True, True) 
    Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWare")
          
    
    srcWS.Pictures(4).Copy 
    dstWS.Range("A8").PasteSpecial
```

The size of the picture from the raw file is H: 3.59" x W 8.14"

Sample Output:
[image]

Comment: Your question is whether or not it can be done all/only in VBA? Yes. It can be done.

Comment: To tell you where to start, it would be helpful to know where you stand knowlegde wise. Do you know how to open the VBE? Do you have some VBA experience? etc.

Comment: I know how some basic data manipulation but I am still reading about creating or generating a dynamic sheet.

Comment: The image you show is one of the the source files? or is it the master workbook? please show an image or a mockup of the respective other view. On a sidenote, it is not a good idea to have merged cells when working with vba. in fact, you should always avoid them. they cause nothing but trouble.

Comment: It is the destination/master sheet. I will edit my post to include the source.

Comment: For the destination I would need: the workbook name, worksheet name, the cell addresses of `Header`, of the image and of `title` and the column widths including the 'gap' columns between two results. For the source I would need the folder path of the source files (do subfolders have to be searched), the worksheet name (index), the image name and size, the two cell addresses and sample cell contents, a description if there is extraction needed from the cells and an explanation of how the cells are combined in `sample title` of destination. An image of the exact desired result would be useful.

Comment: @VBasic2008 added more info on the post.

Comment: I've seen it and it's a start. I'll try to do something tomorrow and ask for missing info. In the meantime if you could check my answer to your other question and in the comments inform me what should be changed. Surely we'll have to wait for a maybe more efficient solution to be applied in this big project.

Comment: @VBasic2008 btw, the other question is a different approach to my issue.

Comment: Why not use Power Query for something like this??

Answer (score 3):

So let's try to give this a start...

First of all, it's quite easy, using some functions like this for my work aswell.

First of all you gotta ask yourself how maintainable you want to make this, cause if you want to maintain a lot I would suggest a class Module and a Macro.

As far As I understand you want to go through all the excels in a folder, there we got a good script to make this easy and possible, you can run it alone so try it out.

**For more help I need more details from what you want to do, since this is all you asked you may give us more informations, you can add now a counter where you add +1 every time it opens an excel file in the folder, so you can track the number of excel files in the folder.**

```
    Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
    
    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)
    
    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Report

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createCPU()
    
    Const ProcName As String = "createCPU"
    On Error GoTo clearError

    ' Source
    Const Extension As String = "xlsx"
    Const srcName As String = "Microsoft.SystemCenter.DataWare"
    Const srcList As String = "J20,J18"
    Const picIndex As Long = 1
    Const SubFolder As String = "\CPU"
    ' Destination
    Const dstWbName As String = "master.xlsx"
    Const dstName As String = "CPU"
    Const dstAddr As String = "A1:G38"
    Const dstList As String = "B2,B29" ' B2 instead of B5 because of 'Merge'.
    Const dstMergeOffset As Long = 3
    Const picAddress As String = "A8"
    Const colOffset As Long = 7
    
    ' Write file paths from Source Folder Path to File Paths array.
    Dim srcFolderPath As String: srcFolderPath = Thisworkbook.Path & SubFolder
    Dim FilePaths As Variant
    FilePaths = getFilePathsInFolder(srcFolderPath, Extension, 1) ' one-based
    If IsEmpty(FilePaths) Then
        MsgBox "No matching workbooks found in folder '" & srcFolderPath _
            & "'!", vbCritical, "Fail"
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Write cell addresses to arrays.
    Dim srcCells() As String: srcCells = Split(srcList, ",") ' zero-based
    Dim dstCells() As String: dstCells = Split(dstList, ",") ' zero-based
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Format destination worksheet.
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Set wbDst = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & dstWbName)
    Dim dst As Worksheet: Set dst = wbDst.Worksheets(dstName)
    clearTemplate dst
    formatTemplate dst
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fpCount As Long
    Dim fp As Long
    fpCount = UBound(FilePaths)
    If fpCount > 1 Then
        For fp = 2 To fpCount
            With dst.Range(dstAddr)
                Set rng = dst.Range(dstAddr).Offset(, (fp - 1) * colOffset)
                formatColumnWidths rng
                .Copy rng
            End With
        Next fp
    End If
    
    ' Copy data.
    
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim srcCount As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For fp = 1 To fpCount
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(FilePaths(fp), True, True)
        Set src = wbSrc.Worksheets(srcName)
        src.Pictures(picIndex).Copy
        dst.Range(picAddress).Offset(, (fp - 1) * colOffset).PasteSpecial
        ' A Merge Trick (Offset doesn't work with merged cells so well.)
        dst.Range(dstCells(0)).Offset(dstMergeOffset, (fp - 1) * colOffset) _
            .Value = src.Range(srcCells(0)).Value
        dst.Range(dstCells(1)).Offset(, (fp - 1) * colOffset).Value _
            = src.Range(srcCells(0)).Value & vbLf _
            & src.Range(srcCells(1)).Value
        wbSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next fp
    
    ' Save and/or inform user.
    dst.Range("A1").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Suppressing Document Inspector message.
    wbDst.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If fpCount = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Data from 1 workbook transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Data from " & fpCount & " workbooks transferred.", _
            vbInformation, "Success"
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
    
End Sub

Function getFilePathsInFolder( _
    FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal ExtensionPattern As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal FirstIndex As Long = 0) _
As Variant
    
    Const ProcName As String = "getFilePathsInFolder"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim fsoFolder As Object
        Set fsoFolder = .GetFolder(FolderPath)
        Dim FilesCount As Long
        FilesCount = fsoFolder.Files.Count
        If FilesCount > 0 Then
            Dim n As Long
            n = FirstIndex - 1
            Dim OneD As Variant
            ReDim OneD(FirstIndex To FilesCount + n)
            Dim fsoFile As Object
            If ExtensionPattern = "" Then
                For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
                    n = n + 1
                    OneD(n) = fsoFile.Path
                Next fsoFile
                getFilePathsInFolder = OneD
            Else
                For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
                    If LCase(.GetExtensionName(fsoFile)) _
                            Like LCase(ExtensionPattern) Then
                        n = n + 1
                        OneD(n) = fsoFile.Path
                    End If
                Next fsoFile
                If n > FirstIndex - 1 Then
                    ReDim Preserve OneD(FirstIndex To n)
                    getFilePathsInFolder = OneD
                Else
                    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                        & "No '" & ExtensionPattern & "'-files found."
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
                & "No files found."
        End If
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected error!" & vbLf _
        & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
        & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Function

Sub clearTemplate(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear
        .Columns.ColumnWidth = 8.43
        .Pictures.Delete
    End With
End Sub

Sub formatTemplate(ws As Worksheet)
    
    With ws
        ' Column Widths
        formatColumnWidths (.Columns("A:G"))
        
        ' Title 1
        With .Range("B2")
            .Value = "CPU"
            With .Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Size = 20
                .Bold = True
            End With
        End With
        
        ' Title 2
        With .Range("B5:F6")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            With .Font
               .Name = "Calibri"
               .Size = 16
               .Bold = False
            End With
        End With
        
        ' Table
                
        ' Headers
        With .Range("B28:E28")
            .Interior.Color = 16776960
            .Value = Array("Graph name", "No.", "Analysis", "Status")
        End With
        ' Yellow
        With .Range("B29")
            .Interior.Color = 65535
        End With
        
        ' Body
        
        ' Graph name - yellow
        With .Range("B29:B34")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        
        ' No.
        With .Range("C29:C30")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Value = 1
        End With
        With .Range("C31:C32")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Value = 2
        End With
        With .Range("C33:C34")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Value = 3
        End With
        
        ' Analysis
        With .Range("D29:D30")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With .Range("D31:D32")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With .Range("D33:D34")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        
        ' Status
        With .Range("E29:E30")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With .Range("E31:E32")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With .Range("E33:E34")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        
        ' Empty Box
        
        With .Range("B36:E38")
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .WrapText = False
        End With
        
    End With

End Sub

Sub formatColumnWidths(rng As Range)
    With rng.EntireColumn
        .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 8.43
        .Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 11.43
        .Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 4.29
        .Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 63
        .Columns(5).ColumnWidth = 8.43
        .Columns(6).ColumnWidth = 2.71
        .Columns(7).ColumnWidth = 8.43
    End With
End Sub
```